# Using phpseclib to close a Net_SFTP connection

Tags: php, phpseclib, net-sftp

I have a program written in PHP that distributes files to various FTP sites. Recently, I added SFTP support to it using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). It's very easy to use to log in and upload the files.

However, there doesn't seem to be an explicit function to close a connection. This is important to me because I'm dealing with connecting  /disconnecting to a number of sites during the processing.

How can I close a Net_SFTP connection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does undefining your connection work ([as mentioned in this Perl 5 example](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?460511-how-to-close-SFTP-connection))?

```
unset($sftp);
```

where `$sftp` is the variable holding your connection.

Comment: The destructor will log you out. You can also do `$sftp->disconnect()`.

Comment: @neubert By "The destructor will log you out." do you mean "Whenever `$sftp` goes out of scope, it will automatically close the connection"?